# Crash with a loop which look in a mutable array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an issue with my App when I try to use a for loop to look in a NSMutable Array called endpoints here. To explain the program quickly, I have a class which collect different endpoint of an URL from an API and create an associate view. The code bellow show the part where I use these endpoints (sometime I have just one for a view but I can have more for other view)

So this is the part which has an issue (when I launch the app it crashes)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _scheduleList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _futurScheduleList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _currentScheduleList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _pastScheduleList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


        for (id item in self.endpoints) {
            NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://apis.is%@", item];
            NSData *JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
            // Parse JSON
            NSError *error;
            if (JSONData) {
                NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                                      JSONObjectWithData:JSONData //1

                                      options:kNilOptions
                                      error:&error];
                NSArray *jsonResult = [json objectForKey:@"results"];
                for (id item in jsonResult) {
                    TVShow *tvs = [[TVShow alloc] init];
                    tvs.title = [item objectForKey:@"title"];
                    tvs.startTime = [item objectForKey:@"startTime"];
                    tvs.duration = [item objectForKey:@"duration"];
                    tvs.episode = [item valueForKeyPath:@"series.episode"];
                    tvs.serie = [item valueForKeyPath:@"series.series"];
                    tvs.theDescription = [item objectForKey:@"description"];

                    if ([self isItAFuturShow:tvs]) {
                        [_futurScheduleList addObject:tvs];
                    }

                    if ([self isItAPastShow:tvs]) {
                        [_pastScheduleList addObject:tvs];
                    }

                    if ([self isTimeForAShow:tvs]) {
                        [_currentScheduleList addObject:tvs];
                    }

                    [_scheduleList addObject:tvs];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I look at the error I have that :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa00f048fc1508fc8'
```

When I check 0xa00f048fc1508fc8, I have something inside

The error pop at this line `for (id item in self.endpoints)`

Thanks for your help

Comment: Which line exactly if causing the issue? `for (id item in jsonResult)`? Could be because `jsonResult` is a `NSString`. Do you have a small example of what `json` looks like?.

Comment: No, this one `for (id item in self.endpoints)`

Comment: Great, so you're showing another piece of code which seems irrelevant?

Comment: Yes I don't now why my endpoint is considered as a NSTaggedPointerString because It has been defined like that : `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *endpoints;`

Comment: If you do `NSArray *arrayOfStrings = @[@"Hey"]; _endPoints = [arrayOfStrings firstObject]`, it's a `NSMutableArray` property, but you still put a `NSString` inside... Same seems to be occurring in your code.

Comment: Hum yes I see but how can fix that when I do that in that part : `scheduleListTableViewController.endpoints = item[@"endpoint"];`
when I look in the API

Comment: `item[@"endpoint"]` seems to be a `NSString`. So how is that supposed to be a NSArray?

Comment: Yes it's a NSTaggedPointerString

Comment: When I try that @Larme, it returns nil : `[scheduleListTableViewController.endpoints addObject: item[@"endpoint"]]` , is there a syntax error ?

Comment: Never mind I forget to allocate it